# Input layer initialization Keras for rank 0 tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

How do we initialize an Input tensor of rank 0, i.e, a scalar value.

I'm doing this:

```
a = Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.bool)
```

In my custom layer, I try to print the particular input in the call() function and I get this:

```
Tensor("input_4:0", shape=(?,), dtype=bool)
```

Hence, I'm getting the error saying the rank is supposed be 0 but it is 1. Any idea?

Comment: Does it work with `Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.bool)`?

Comment: In that case, you could maybe access the first element of `a` (i.e. `a[0]`) in your custom layer. If this doesn't solve your problem, could you please add a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: Yes. That's what I did. I passed a rank 1 tensor and access the 0th element from it. @rvinas . Thanks!

Comment: No, it still didn't work. @sdcbr